# How to Display Users who Close a Task

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

I got a question on how to display the user who close a task in Dynamics CRM. I see there is no specific field for this and I'm wondering if I could just use the 'Modified By' field, after the task is closed. Is there a risk for doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ModifiedBy will contain the latest user who performed an update to a record. It's relatively safe to assume that this field will contain the user who closed the task.

Answer (score 0):

Just have in mind:

Closed tasks can still be modified/updated by API, Plugins or Workflows which will than also change the modifiedby field again.